# Cardinal of measures

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathscr{X}=([0,1],\mathcal{B},\mu)$ be a measure space, and $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra with the subspace topology of the euclidean real line.

We will look at $A:=\{f\mid f:\mathcal{P}([0,1])\rightarrow [0,\infty]\}$, $B:=\{f\in A \mid f$ is $\sigma$-additive on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra$\}$, $C:=\{f\in A \mid f(\emptyset)=0\}$, and $D:=\{f\in A \mid \mathscr{Y}=([0,1],\mathcal{B},f)$ is a measure space$\}$.

Of course $C\cap B=D$, and $A, B, C, D \neq \emptyset$ because Lebesgue measure $\in A, B, C, D$.

In particular, $A\cap B\cap C\cap D\neq\emptyset$.

Of course $\mid C\cap B \mid \leqslant \aleph^{(2^\aleph)}$ because $C\cap B\subset A$.

My question: $\mid C\cap B \mid=\mid D \mid=?$

Thanks for helping.

Comment: (Before the usual comments start, $\aleph$ is sometimes used to denote the cardinality of the continuum, especially in Israel. Any complaints can be sent to Hausdorff.)

Comment: Perhaps show that a measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal B$ is determined by its values $\mu([a,b])$ with $a,b \in \mathbb Q$.  That would tell us $|D| = 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: An objection to what I said. Perhaps my argument will only work for finite measures.  If $\mu([a,b]) = \infty$ for all rationals $a\le b$, you still doin't know $\mu(\{a\})$ for irrational $a$.

Comment: @GEdgar It seems you're talking about Vitali covering lemma, am I right?